# Entity framework query one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables:

[image]

in entity framework model with relationship one to many. 
I want to select all Instructors who have Disposition with Begin for example 24.1.2016 9:00 and also Disposition with Begin 24.1.2016 10:00.
I don't know how to do it in one LINQ method or LINQ query.
I have this code.

```
List<instructor> result = new List<instructor>();
        DateTime date = new DateTime(2016,1,24,9,0,0);
        var dispositions = Db.disposition.AsQueryable();
        var instructorsTen = Db.instructor.AsQueryable();
        var instructorsNine = Db.instructor.AsQueryable();            

        instructorsNine = from i in instructorsNine from d in i.disposition where d.begin == date select d.instructor;
        date= date.AddHours(1);
        instructorsTen = from i in instructorsTen from d in i.dispozice where d.begin == date select d.instructor;

        foreach (instructor insNine in instructorsNine) {
            foreach (instructor insTen in instructorsTen) {
                if (insNine.ID == insTen.ID) result.Add(insNine);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select all Instructors who have Disposition with Begin for example 24.1.2016 9:00 and also Disposition with Begin 24.1.2016 10:00.

You can use the **navigation property** and [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.100).aspx) like this

```
var date1 = new DateTime(2016,1,24,9,0,0);
var date2 = date1.AddHours(1);
var result = Db.instructor
    .Where(i => i.disposition.Any(d => d.begin == date1)
        && i.disposition.Any(d => d.begin == date2));
```